# Microsoft dynamics ax 2012 How to create autolookup from 2 different tables

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I just realised that im facing huge problem on my project. I have 3 tables- slimnica(Hospital), nodala(Department) and telpa(Room). There are hundreds of Hospitals, Departments and rooms. When im filling table Room, i must select ID from table Department, but the problem is, one multiple hospitals can have example, Surgery department. It means, when im filling up Room table, i can put autolookup Departments name, but then it will show multiple Surgery departments. Is there a way to also show name of Hospital in autolookup? I added link down below of my tables.

Tables: Slimnica(Hospital), nodala(Department), telpa(Room)

[image: 1]

Example:

I have 3 different hospitals, but all of them has Surgery department. When im filling up Room table, i must select what depertment it is, so i select departments id(it will show department name, because of autolookup name) and it will show me 3 options - id 1, surgery. id 2, surgery. id 3, surgery. Is it possible to make a autolookup that will also show hospital where that department is??? example - id 1, surgery, Childrens traumatology hospital.

Comment: For the *lookups* though, check the Dev docs, specifically [Configuring the Lookup for a Data Set Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/configuring-the-lookup-for-a-data-set-field)

Comment: In which form i must write this code? In room, right? It looks like, that dev docs code is for only 2 tables, not 3 (my case)

Comment: Have you looked at a custom lookup form https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-add-a-lookup-form-to-a-control or `\Forms\tutorial_LookupMultiSelectGrid` in the AOT. It sounds like you just need to use a `query` with your lookup though. What have you tried?